# Códigos de barra das caixas de produtos são adequados para chaves primárias?

Tags: banco-de-dados, código-de-barras

### **Situação**

Em um sistema onde os produtos serão armazenados no banco de dados, e o código de barras é um campo único, gostaria de saber se os códigos de barra que vem nas caixas dos produtos tem a possibilidade de se repetirem com produtos diferentes. A empresa trabalha com equipamentos de rede, há uma alternativa de identificar os produtos pelo MAC, porém eles também trabalham com alguns produtos que não possuem MAC.

### **Resumindo**

Eu não conheço nada a respeito dos códigos de barra e a possibilidade deles repetirem.

Comment: Depende do tipo de barras. Se for tudo UPC, como é normal em produtos industrializados, não repetem. Mas tem gente que usa barras pra controle interno, nesse caso, complica. Notar que se está falando de identificação única, (dois produtos iguais com código diferente), só fazendo o seu próprio sistema de etiquetamento. E MACs podem se repetir, apesar de num mundo ideal isso não acontecer, na realidade não é bem assim. Principalmente se forem vários fabricantes diferentes. Nem todos usam os mesmos critérios.

Comment: Sim, eles precisam saber se um equipamento está com algum funcionário, ou está no estoque, por exemplo. O controle atual é identificado pelo endereço MAC, porém eles estão com uma problemática na identificação dos outros produtos que estão trabalhando, justamente por não seguirem um padrão consistente.

Comment: Melhor coisa é fazer as etiquetas de controle da empresa. Chegou produto, obrigar a etiquetar pra poder dar entrada. Ninguem faz nada se nao tiver o serial. Com serial unico, vc tem rastreabilidade total. Se nao puder abrir a caixa, faça em 2 etapas. Ao abrir o produto, tem que anotar que abriu no cadastro daquele serial, e anotar a etiqueta definitiva (interna). Assim, com futuros usos da etiqueta de caixa, o sistema avisa "o produto já foi desembalado, favor usar etiqueta interna". Claro, sao idéias gerais. Tem que adaptar à sua realidade. O ideal mesmo é etiqueta inviolável de série única.

Comment: Ao invés de tentar encontrar um campo único em string, por que não coloca um id genérico integer e auto-incrementável? se precisar deixar o campo string como único, marque-o como unique key, não coloque campo string como identificador de uma tabela. imagina se a tabela tem 1 milhão de registros a busca em string é muito mais lenta em bancos de dados. sei que é regra de banco  de dados "encontrar algo que não se repete" e marcar como chave, mas e se depois você descobrir que o seu campo "que não se repete" não é bem assim, vai criar um chave composta? não te aconselho a fazer isso.

Comment: Obrigado @Geferson, mas em hipótese alguma cogitei em colocar o MAC ou o ID como chave primária da tabela, cada registro já tem uma chave primária auto incremental, no caso desse identificador único que era pra ser o código de barras, é apenas para evitar registros duplicados. Também não pensei em chave composta, mas cogitei deixar o MAC e o código de barras como único. Vou conversar com a impressa e sugerir o uso de códigos de barra pra controle interno (códigos usados somente dentro da empresa). Obrigado, caso tenha alguma sugestão será bem vinda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Códigos de barra das caixas de produtos são adequados para chaves
>   primárias?

Respondendo a pergunta, não, nunca é bom tornar público o identificador de um registro do banco. Informações públicas, mesmo que sejam únicas como um código de barras, costumam ser apenas associadas a constraints UNIQUE no banco de dados que possuem como ID outra numeração gerada internamente.

Answer (score 0):

Não mesmo, chave primaria tem que ser única ok, isso mesmo, mas ser uma informação que o usuário possa mexer coloca em risco toda a sua tabela. Além de ser mais otimizada se for de tipo numérico, o que não conseguiria fazer usando código de barras.